# Is there any security risk to use getenv() inside settings.php to populate databases variable from a .env file?

Tags: installation

I am using the Drupal composer project, which doesn't use `getenv()` by default.  I wanted to use the following code inside the settings.php file in a production site.

```
  $databases['default']['default'] = array (
   'database' => getenv('MYSQL_DATABASE'),
   'username' => getenv('MYSQL_USER'),
   'password' => getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD'),
   'prefix' => '',
   'host' => getenv('MYSQL_HOSTNAME'),
   'port' => getenv('MYSQL_PORT'),
   'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
   'driver' => 'mysql',
);
```

I read somewhere we shouldn't use `getenv()` in production sites. What are the downsides of it? Is there any security issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the .env file is outside the server document root, using `getenv()` is similar to putting the hash salt in a file and reading it with `file_get_contents()` as the following comments in the [default.settings.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/sites%21default%21default.settings.php/8.6.x) file suggest to do. (The same comment is present in the default.settings.php file for Drupal 7, so it's not a matter of which Drupal version is used.)

```
/**
 * Salt for one-time login links, cancel links, form tokens, etc.
 *
 * This variable will be set to a random value by the installer. All one-time
 * login links will be invalidated if the value is changed. Note that if your
 * site is deployed on a cluster of web servers, you must ensure that this
 * variable has the same value on each server.
 *
 * For enhanced security, you may set this variable to the contents of a file
 * outside your document root; you should also ensure that this file is not
 * stored with backups of your database.
 *
 * Example:
 * @code
 *   $settings['hash_salt'] = file_get_contents('/home/example/salt.txt');
 * @endcode
 */
$settings['hash_salt'] = '';
```

If that is considered enhanced security, the same can be said for reading some values using `getenv()`, if the file containing the values of the environment variables is not in the server document root.

Keep in mind that, if somebody would be able to write a PHP file on the server, it would also be possible for them to read the environment variables and the file containing the hash salt.

Answer (score 1):

You may be telling about this **Production environments rarely use .env files.**. Someday I also went through this line. Though still I don't know what is this why it has been written like this ?

```
<?php
/**
 * This file is included very early. See autoload.files in composer.json and
 * https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files
 */
use Dotenv\Dotenv;
use Dotenv\Exception\InvalidPathException;
/**
 * Load any .env file. See /.env.example.
 */
$dotenv = new Dotenv(__DIR__);
try {
  $dotenv->load();
}
catch (InvalidPathException $e) {
  // Do nothing. Production environments rarely use .env files.
}
```

https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project/blob/8.x/load.environment.php